# TextTrimming without Ellipsis

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm drawing text directly through the `DrawingContext` to a control. The text is multiline and must fit in to a certain (computed) width. If a line is too long then it should be trimmed.

Now, WPF allows me to use `TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis` to automatically trim the text, however it insists on adding ellipsis when trimming the text. As I want to show as much text as possible (without TextWrap) I'm asking if there is a function to get trimming without ellipsis, e.g. just showing the characters which fit in to the specified width.

Currently I am using `dc.PushClip`/`dc.Pop` to just cut of the text at the desired width. However, this leads to words being cut of mid-character.

I guess I could get every line of the text seperately and then compute the length of the formatted text (until I have the maximal fitting text), but this seems rather complicated (and possibly even slow, as I am showing quite a lot of text).

Is there a built-in function to trim text to a certain width without ellipsis? Maybe using P/Invoke?

EDIT (in response to Peter Dunhiho): I am using `TextTrimming.None`. If I do this without pushing a clip to the DrawingContext then the text will just (depending on the MaxTextWidth) will either be written over the current boundaries or go to the next line.

Currently I am doing following:

```
public void Render(double left, double top, double width, double height, DrawingContext dc)
{

   FormattedText text = new FormattedText(text,
                                       CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,                                                                                     
                                       FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                                       ArialTypeFace, 12,                                 
                                       BrushDictionary.SolidBlack);

   text.Trimming = TextTrimming.None;
   text.MaxTextWidth = width + 5;
   text.MaxTextHeight = height;
   dc.PushClip(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(left,                             
   top, width-0.5, height - 0.5)));
   dc.DrawText(text, new Point(left, top));
   dc.Pop();
}
```

This will correctly put the text (which has multiple lines) in the desired rectangle. However, the text will be cut off mid-character if one of the lines of the text is too long. I would rather have the last character which fits into the designated rectangle be displayed and the rest cut off for each line.

EDIT 2:

Example Text:

```
This is just a random text 
which spans multiple lines
```

With TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis:

```
This is jus...
which spans...
```

Current method:

```
This is just a
which spans mu
```

The current method (with clipping) may clip directly through the last char of the line, this is what I want to prevent!

Comment: I do not know the answer but can you get the text width in advance and draw only the text you know is going to fit into your area?

Comment: @Samuel Yep, that would be possible, but as I wrote this would require a lot of code and operations. I first would have to split the text by lines. Then for every line I would have to check if the text fits in to the specified width. If not I would have to get the substring of the line which fits into the width (first getting the maximal amount of chars which will fit in the desired width using a FormattedText). This is possible, but if there is an easier (e.g. predefined) way I would rather let WPF/Windows do this... (trying not to reinvent the wheel)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Added my current code.

Comment: Hmya, this is a common culture bias.  It is hard enough in English: (Hello)world.  But what is the 'last character' in 你好世界 or مرحبا بالعالم.?  Ellipsis is the solution, not the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I see, thanks for the information. Luckily I ever only have to handle latin characters (as per specification). So, there is no built in function to do this?